# Draw a line if condition is met to current candle in tradingview/pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw a line from crossovers or crossunders of 2 Moving averages to current candle low or high or from lowest low of 20 candle to current candle low/high...Can these condition's be used in barindex.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.